# Compile OSX app on Windows with Xamarin

Tags: windows, macos, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.mac

I have a Xamarin Mac app I've been handed to make some changes. I've got everything working correctly as far as Windows Visual Studio Xamarin connecting to Mac Xamarin -- the Mac ssh agent works and whatnot.

However, how do I compile the app? When I build it on Windows, it generates an .exe file. Is something supposed to be generated on the Mac side, too? Or do I take that .exe file and somehow package it into an OSX app?

I was trying to stay in my Windows environment to do the coding and building as much as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Mac's use `.app` bundles, not `.exe`, so I would say there's something amiss.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to compile/package/debug it on macOS.

> The build process is performed locally on Windows, generating IL assemblies that cannot be used for running or debugging apps, and it doesn't create application bundles.

re: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/#Xamarin.Mac_minimum_support.

> macOS Apps
>   Mac apps can be opened and compiled in Visual Studio to check for errors, however to debug or create a working executable the project must currently be built on a Mac. This limited support for Mac projects allows for easier code sharing in Visual Studio between iOS, Android, Windows, and Mac apps.

re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/visual-studio/#macOS_Apps

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.