# How to create a MacOS Console App using VS on Windows

Tags: macos, xamarin, console-application

.NET Core 3.1  Visual Studio 2019

I have created an iOS Xamarin mobile app, using Visual Studio running on Windows.  All works fine, even debugging on an iPhone connected to the Mac on my network.

I now need a very simple Console App for the actual Mac (macOS computer).  I have already written the Windows version of the Console App.

I cannot work out how to compile the Console App for macOS.  Is it possible?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can write a .NET Core console app and then deploy it to the Mac

Comment: Hi ,I think SushiHangover's said is right . If answer be helpful , remember to mark it when you have time .

Answer (score 3):

If it is not using `Xamarin.Mac` APIs, then you can "just" use the console app assembl(ies) and run it via `dotnet`

Or `publish` it via `dotnet` as a `self-contained executable`

```
dotnet publish --runtime osx.10.11-x64
```

Or a `runtime-dependent cross-platform binary`

```
dotnet publish
```

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

But if your app is using `Xamarin.Mac` APIs, then review my SO answer here:

re: [Compile OSX app on Windows with Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298019/compile-osx-app-on-windows-with-xamarin)